# How to create procedure to select from table as parameter

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to select parameter as a table name in oracle procedure as per the code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLENAME_BY_PARAMETER(pr_tbname IN VARCHAR, v_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is BEGIN open v_cursor for select *from pr_tbname; END GET_TABLENAME_BY_PARAMETER;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL can be constructed to return refcursor for the input tablename.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLENAME_BY_PARAMETER(pr_tbname IN VARCHAR, v_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) is 
BEGIN open v_cursor for ' select * from '||pr_tbname; 
END GET_TABLENAME_BY_PARAMETER;
```